# Add a attribute value to a div without class or id?

Tags: css, class, html, z-index

I want to add a z-index value to a div that I don't have access to and has no id or class, plus there are more than one layers above all in the same way. The difference between these layers is that, the 3rd one (the one i'm interested in) has a z-index value attached (hard coded, not available from template files, i can't touch anything but the template files).

So what I want is to find a way to change the z-index value of this div.

For example the code looks like this:

```
<div>
<div>
<div style="z-index:2">

..some content..

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Can I wrap this code in another layer, this time with a class name or ID and then try to make the change to the div inside? Is this possible?

Thank you very much!

Comment: make a wrapper and use id or class to get access to it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the `z-index` is hard-coded, you can use an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Attribute_selectors) to select the element ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s62Jn/)):

```
div[style*="z-index:2"]
```

This even works when you change the CSS through jQuery using [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/), or through JavaScript using `.style.cssText`, because the selector selects elements by its **attribute**, not by its **property**.

Comment: Wow this is so cool, I did not know that.. I got a lot to learn! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about cross-browser compatibilities you can use the [:nth-child()](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-nthchild) pseudoclass in your css selector.

Something like

```
(parent div) div:nth-child(3)
```